# Add items to array within classes

Tags: c#

I am new to programming in C#. I guess it might be a very easy solution which I am not aware of .

Suppose I have a class file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace sharepointproject1
{
    public partial class School
    {
        public students[] students { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class student
    {
        public marks[] marks;
        public extraactivites[] extraactivities;
    }
    public partial class marks
    {
        public int m1 { get; set; }
        public int m2 { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class extraactivities
    {
        public decimal m5;
        public decimal m6;

    }
}
```

Now in aspx.cs file how do I add marks to the array declared?

```
namespace sharepointproject1
{
    public partial class testing : usercontrol
    {
        School school = new school();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            school.students[0].marks[0].mark1 = 45;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to dynamically add items to it at run time. How do I do that? Do I have to change the array to list array in the class file..Hope I am making some sense out of my question.Later I need to bind the marks to the gridview.

Please help!

Comment: I would recommend [`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). Or build your own [`System.Collections.CollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase.aspx) of the objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed size - use a more flexible collection such as `List<T>`, which will grow as you need it to.

Eric Lippert has a good blog post about why [arrays should be considered somewhat harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx).

Additionally:

- You should look into the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)
- Only use partial classes when you actually need to, which I suspect you don't here
- Don't expose public fields; use properties instead. However, don't just expose everything as a property: consider more encapsulation. You don't necessarily want callers to be able to replace whole collections, but just (say) add or remove students, or access them by index.
- Consider making some of your classes immutable (most obviously Marks and ExtraActivities)

Comment: +1, for the obligatory "up-vote for Jon Skeet post". (Don't we have a greasemonkey script for this somewhere?) Also, interesting article on arrays, thanks for the posting.

Comment: Should ArrayLists be considered as harmful as Arrays?

Comment: @IAbstract: I'd consider ArrayList as obsolete in modern .NET code rather than harmful... arrays still have their place in modern code, but should be used with care.

Comment: I will surely look into the points that you mentioned. It willbe helpful if you could post a sample code taking my example and guide me how i should be adding items to it.

Comment: @Janet: I'm afraid I don't have time for that right now - could I suggest you get hold of a good (modern) introductory C# book? Any introductory book worth its salt should cover collections, and it'll be a much better way of learning than just via SO.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is forget arrays and use `List` or `List<T>` which is the generic List.
Not only because solves the dynamic part of of your problem, but also has better performance avoiding box and unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change Array to something that can grow dynamically like List<>. It may be better option to add methods like AddMark(marks mark) to student class and perform Add operation inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're stuck for some reason in .NET 1.0 I'd strongly recommend looking at the Collection classes and then generics available in .NET.  These will allow you to replace the array[] declarations with List where T is a .NET type. e.g

```
public class Student
{
    public List<Mark> Marks{get;set;}
}

public class Mark
{
    public int SomePropertyA { get; set; }
    public int SomePropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. Definitely Lists are more dynamic than the array , i still have to continue using Array as per our project. I would really want someone to help me how do I go about adding items to the class that I have declared in my question.